# ecto crashes in phoenix project detecting stack smashing

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm in a phoenix project, and `mix ecto.create`, `mix ecto.migrate`, and `mix ecto.drop` all emit the same error:

```
$ mix ecto.drop
==> tzdata
Compiled lib/tzdata/parser_organizer.ex
Compiled lib/tzdata/release_parser.ex
Compiled lib/tzdata/util.ex
Compiled lib/tzdata/table_parser.ex
Compiled lib/tzdata/parser.ex
Compiled lib/tzdata/table_data.ex
Compiled lib/tzdata/leap_sec_parser.ex
Compiled lib/tzdata/basic_data.ex
Compiled lib/tzdata/period_builder.ex
Compiled lib/tzdata/far_future_dynamic_periods.ex

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...*** stack smashing detected ***: /usr/lib/erlang/erts-7.0/bin/beam terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: what do you see when you tail erl_crash.dump?

Comment: `Slogan: eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 123210440 bytes of memory (of type "heap").` Seems I haven't allocated enough memory for my virtual machine. I feel bad having not realized that file was written. Thank you @emaillenin

Answer (score 3):

Virtualbox machine didn't have enough memory. After allocating more memory, this problem went away.

Comment: I have too little cred to make this the accepted answer.